# Get second number from (1_2_3_4)

Tags: php, regex

How to get the second string from a long string written like this:

```
1200_500_test_5.3_test2
```

i.e.: I want to get only the second section form this words or numbers that have `_` between each of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions. Just use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode):

```
$input = '1200_500_test_5.3_test2';
$output = explode('_', $input, 3);
echo $output[1]; // 500
```

But if you *must* use a regular expression, use this:

```
$input = '1200_500_test_5.3_test2';
preg_match('/(?<=_)[^_]+/', $input, $output);
echo $output[0]; // 500
```

Or this:

```
$input = '1200_500_test_5.3_test2';
preg_match('/(?:(?:[^_]+)_)([^_]+)/', $input, $output);
echo $output[1]; // 500
```

And to get the third group (replace `2` with *n-1* to get group *n*:

```
$input = '1200_500_test_5.3_test2';
preg_match('/(?:(?:[^_]+)_){2}([^_]+)/', $input, $output);
echo $output[1]; // test
```

Comment: I want to use regex only beacuse I stored values like example at mysql database and I want to apply some queries

Comment: if I want to get third or fourth section, what should i change at regex?

Comment: @زهيرطه In that case you can't use a lookbehind (because PHP doesn't support variable-length lookbehind). See my updated answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

If you always want to get the second number after the first underscore, you don't even need a regexp:

```
$numbers = explode( '_', '1200_500_test_5.3_test2' );
var_dump( $numbers[1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $str  = "1200_500_test_5.3_test2";
   $pieces = explode('_', $str);
   echo $pieces[1];
```